Existence of a function $ f(x)$ and values $( a, b, c, d )$ satisfying specific conditions in $[0,1]$
I am trying to know whether there exists a function $f(x)$ and values $a, b, c, d$ in the interval $[0,1]$ that satisfy the following three conditions:
1: $f(x) \in [0,1]$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$ and $f(x)$ is increasing.
2: $a, b, c, d \in [0, 1]$ and $c > a$,  $d > b$.
3: $f(cd) + f(ab) < f(cb) + f(ad)$.
I am seeking a proof or counterexample to determine if such a function $f(x)$ and values $a, b, c, d$ can exist.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to approach this problem. Thank you in advance for your help!

To try for a simple and concrete example, let's first choose simple points. If $a=0$ the inequality is impossible:
$$ f(cd) + f(0) < f(cb) + f(0) $$
but since $f$ is increasing, $d>b$, and $c \geq 0$, we instead have $f(cb) < f(cd)$.
So say $a=b=\frac 12$ and $c=d=1$. Then we want to find $f$ so that
$$ f(1) + f\!\left(\frac 14\right) < 2f\!\left(\frac 12\right) $$
If we imagine $f(x)$ has some certain values at $x=\frac 14$ and $x=1$, we see it helps to increase $f\!\left(\frac 12\right)$ (though it must remain less than $f(1)$. This suggests a concave down function.
So how about a quadratic with negative $x^2$ sign, and fitting in the $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ graph?
$$ f(x) = 1-(1-x)^2 = 2x-x^2 $$
$f(1)=1$, $f\!\left(\frac 14\right) = \frac{7}{16}$, $f\!\left(\frac 12\right) = \frac 34$, so in fact
$$ f(cd)+f(ab) = \frac{23}{16} < \frac 32 = f(cb) + f(ad) $$
(Not every increasing concave down function works. For example, $\sqrt{x}$ doesn't.)

Here's how I would approach it. Forget $f$ for the moment; just pick some $a, b, c, d$. Let's take, for example, $a = 0.1$, $b = c = 0.2$, and $d = 0.3$. There's nothing special about these points, but it'll be helpful just to commit.
Then, $cd = 0.06$, $ab = 0.02$, $cb = 0.04$, and $ad = 0.03$. If we put these in order, we see that
$$0 < ab < ad < cb < cd < 1.$$
Now, let's assign function values to these points, remembering that $f$ must be increasing, has a codomain of $[0, 1]$, and $f(cd) + f(ab) < f(ad) + f(cb)$. We could choose, for example, $f(ab) = 0.1$, $f(cd) = 0.5$, $f(ad) = 0.3$ and $f(cb) = 0.4$. Note that, with these choices, $f(cd) + f(ab) = 0.6 < 0.7 = f(ad) + f(cb)$, and
$$0 < f(ab) < f(ad) < f(cb) < f(cd) < 1.$$
So, now we just need to extend $f$ to an increasing function on $[0, 1]$, given that $(0.02, 0.1)$, $(0.03, 0.3)$, $(0.04, 0.4)$, and $(0.06, 0.5)$ all lie on the graph.
There are plenty of ways to do this. One way is to simply make the $f$ piecewise constant:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0.1 & \text{if } 0 \le x \le 0.02 \\ 0.3 & \text{if } 0.02 < x \le 0.03 \\ 0.4 & \text{if } 0.03 < x \le 0.04 \\ 0.5 & \text{if } 0.04 < x \le 1.\end{cases}$$
If you want a strictly increasing and/or continuous function, with a bit more work, you could make a piecewise linear function that linearly interpolates these graph points (maybe also assuming that $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$ also lie on the graph). To do this, you would use the linear interpolation formula
$$y = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}(x - x_1) + y_1$$
for the equation of a line between two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ to form lines between each consecutive pair of points (i.e. $(0, 0)$ and $(0.02, 0.1)$, then $(0.02, 0.1)$ and $(0.03, 0.3)$, etc), and form a piecewise function out of these line functions. Because the points all strictly increase and the line segments will join up at the endpoints, the resulting function will be strictly increasing and continuous.

This is how, mechanically, I would approach this question. You have a function that only needs to do something on four points, so I would generally nominate points, and make the function afterwards. While the function being increasing does pose some restriction, you still have overwhelming power to shape the function as you'd like, so pressing ahead with the points first is a good idea.
There are probably examples you can stumble across with familiar, easy formulas, but this kind of method will often lead you to a solution when you have no idea how to proceed.

Notice that, given these constraints, it will always be the case that $cb < cd$ and that $ab < ad$. Since $f$ is increasing, this implies that
$$
f(cb) < f(cd) \text{  and  } f(ab) < f(ad).
$$
Thus we can reduce to finding $a, b, c, d$ such that
$$
f(ad) - f(ab) > f(cd) - f(cb)
$$
(this will also follow from just moving the inequality around, but it helps to make note of this explicitly). I think that in this situation it also helps to investigate what happens when $f$ has "nice" properties. If $f$ respects the multiplication on [0, 1] (i.e., if f is a homomorphism on the multiplicative structure: $x^2$ is such a function) then we see that the above reduces further to
$$
f(a)f(d) - f(a)f(b) > f(c)f(d) - f(c)f(b)
$$
and so we get
$$
f(a)\bigl(f(d) - f(b)\bigr) > f(c)\bigl(f(d) - f(b)\bigr).
$$
Since we're assuming that $a < c$ and $f$ is monotonic, we can deduce from this that $f$ cannot be such a "nice" function; so this doesn't work, but it tells you that $f$, if it exists, cannot be something so simple as, say, $x^n$.

Let us try to satisfy Condition 3 with the additional assumption $a=b$ and $c=d=1$. Then we have to provide $f(1)+f(a^2)<2f(a)$. This can be achieved, for instance, when $a=1/2$, and $f(1)=1$, $f(1/2)=2/3$, and $f(1/4)=1/4$. It remains to require $f(0)<1/4$ and $f$ to be strictly monotonic (for instance, linear) on each of the segment between consecutive points, that is on the segments $[0,1/4]$, $[1/4,1/2]$, and $[1/2,1]$.

A function that has a sharp increase in an appropriate manner will do.
Let us take the function that increases from $(0,0)$ to $(0.1,0.9)$, and then from there to $(1,1)$, both linearly. See the figure below for the plot of this function.

$f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is defined explicitly as
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
9x & \text{if} \quad 0 \le x \le 0.1 , \\
\dfrac19x + \dfrac89 & \text{if} \quad 0.1 < x \le 1 .
\end{cases}$$
With this, we simply take $c=d=1$ and $a=b=0.1$ which clearly satisfies $c>a$ and $d>b$. This gives
$\begin{align}
cd&=1, \qquad \ \, ab=0.01, \qquad \  cb=0.1, \qquad \ \, ad=0.1 \\
\Longrightarrow f(cd)&=1, \quad f(ab)=0.09, \quad f(cb)=0.9, \quad f(ad)=0.9.
\end{align}$
We therefore have $f(cd)+f(ab)=1.09$ and $f(cb)+f(ad)=1.8$ and clearly $1.09 < 1.8$, hence $$\boxed{ f(cd)+f(ab) < f(cb)+f(ad) },$$ as desired. $\blacksquare$
